# Permutate removal of defined substrings with varying length from strings

Tags: python, bash, awk, permutation

I am trying to generate all permutations from a list of strings where certain substrings of characters are removed. I have a list of certain chemical compositions and I want all compositions resulting from that list where one of those elements is removed. A short excerpt of this list looks like this:

```
AlCrHfMoNbN
AlCrHfMoTaN
AlCrHfMoTiN
AlCrHfMoVN
AlCrHfMoWN
...
```

What I am trying to get is

```
 AlCrHfMoNbN --> CrHfMoNbN
                 AlHfMoNbN
                 AlCrMoNbN
                 AlCrHfNbN
                 AlCrHfMoN
AlCrHfMoTaN -->  CrHfMoTaN
                 AlHfMoTaN
                 AlCrMoTaN
                 AlCrHfTaN
                 AlCrHfMoN
```

for each composition. I just need the right column. As you can see some of the resulting compositions are duplicates and this is intended. The list of elements that need to be removed is

```
Al, Cr, Hf, Mo, Nb, Ta, Ti, V, W, Zr
```

As you see some have a length of two characters and some of only one.

There is a question that asks about something very similar, however my problem is more complex:
[Getting a list of strings with character removed in permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502843/getting-a-list-of-strings-with-character-removed-in-permutation)

I tried adjusting the code to my needs:

```
def f(s, c, start):
    i = s.find(c, start)
    return [s] if i < 0 else f(s, c, i+1) + f(s[:i]+s[i+1:], c, i)

s = 'AlCrHfMoNbN'
print(f(s, 'Al', 0))
```

But this simple approach only leads to `['AlCrHfMoNbN', 'lCrHfMoNbN']`. So only one character is removed whereas I need to remove a defined string of characters with a varying length. Also I am limited to a single input object `s` - instead of hundreds that I need to process - so cycling through by hand is not an option.

---

To sum it up what I need is a change in the code that allows to:

- input a list of strings either separated by linebreaks or whitespace
- remove substrings of characters from that list which are defined by a second list (just like above)
- writes the resulting "reduced" items in a continuing list preferably as a single column without any commas and such

Since I only have some experience with Python and Bash I strongly prefer a solution with these languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have gawk, set **FPAT** to `[A-Z][a-z]*` so each element will be regarded as a field, and use a simple loop to generate permutations. also set **OFS** to empty string so there won't be spaces in output records.

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[A-Z][a-z]*";OFS=""} {for(i=1;i<NF;++i){p=$i;$i="";print;$i=p}}' file
CrHfMoNbN
AlHfMoNbN
AlCrMoNbN
AlCrHfNbN
AlCrHfMoN
CrHfMoTaN
AlHfMoTaN
AlCrMoTaN
AlCrHfTaN
AlCrHfMoN
CrHfMoTiN
AlHfMoTiN
AlCrMoTiN
AlCrHfTiN
AlCrHfMoN
CrHfMoVN
AlHfMoVN
AlCrMoVN
AlCrHfVN
AlCrHfMoN
CrHfMoWN
AlHfMoWN
AlCrMoWN
AlCrHfWN
AlCrHfMoN
```

---

I've also written a portable one with extra spaces and explanatory comments:

```
awk '{
  # separate last element from others
  sub(/[A-Z][a-z]*$/, " &")
  # from the beginning of line
  # we will match each element and print a line where it is omitted
  for (i=0; match(substr($1,i), /[A-Z][a-z]*/); i+=RLENGTH)
    print substr($1,1,i)  substr($1,i+RLENGTH+1) $2
    #     ^ before match  ^ after match          ^ last element
}' file
```

Comment: Very nice! Just a minor thing: The "N" at the end is removed by this method as well. Is there an easy way to protect this character at the end so that only 5 permutations are generated per input item? However this is not crucial as I can treat it as an appendix that I can easily remove or add at different stages.

Comment: Great! Could you please explain what your change does? I'm still an eager disciple :)

Comment: @And I've just changed `<=NF` to `<NF` so it'll not remove the last element

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, all you need is `str.replace`:

```
input_list = ['AlCrHfMoNbN', 'AlCrHfMoTaN']
removals = ['Al', 'Cr', 'Hf', 'Mo', 'Nb', 'Ta', 'Ti', 'V', 'W', 'Zr']
result = {}
for i in input_list:
    result[i] = [i.replace(r,'') for r in removals if r in i]
```

Output:

```
{'AlCrHfMoNbN': ['CrHfMoNbN',
  'AlHfMoNbN',
  'AlCrMoNbN',
  'AlCrHfNbN',
  'AlCrHfMoN'],
 'AlCrHfMoTaN': ['CrHfMoTaN',
  'AlHfMoTaN',
  'AlCrMoTaN',
  'AlCrHfTaN',
  'AlCrHfMoN']}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use your attempt, but it works when we assume that your elements always begin with an uppercase letter (and consist otherwise only of lowercase letters):

```
def f(s):
    # split string by elements
    import re
    elements = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', s)

    # make a list of strings, where the first string has the first element removed, the second string the second, ...
    r = []
    for i in range(len(elements)):
        r.append(''.join(elements[:i]+elements[i+1:]))

    # return this list
    return r
```

Of course this still only works for one string. So if you have a list of strings l and you want to apply it for every string in it, just use a for loop like that:

```
# your list of strings
l = ["AlCrHfMoNbN", "AlCrHfMoTaN", "AlCrHfMoTiN", "AlCrHfMoVN", "AlCrHfMoWN"]

# iterate through your input list
for s in l:
    # call above function
    r = f(s)
    # print out the result if you want to
    [print(i) for i in r]
```